# How do i pass an array into a function?

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameters

I have the following code down below that will take an array and write out the correlating pixel colors to the powershell window. The array itself is to form an image. At this point I just have the one image as an example but intend to add more arrays to generate more images. When that time comes I want to be able to pass that array into the function to draw it out. As I have my code now I am getting an error saying

"Cannot index into a null array"

How do I properly pass an Array object into a function?

```
$Colors = @{
    1         =   'White'               
    2         =   'Black'         
    3         =   'DarkBlue'    
    4         =   'DarkGreen'     
    5         =   'DarkCyan'      
    6         =   'DarkRed'       
    7         =   'DarkMagenta'   
    8         =   'DarkYellow'    
    9         =   'Gray'          
    10        =   'DarkGray'      
    11        =   'Blue'          
    12        =   'Green'         
    13        =   'Cyan'          
    14        =   'Red'           
    15        =   'Magenta'       
    16        =   'Yellow'         
}

$omg  =   @(2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1), 
          @(2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2),
          @(2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1),
          @(2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1),
          @(2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1),
          @(2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
          @(2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
          @(2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
          @(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)


Function PS-Draw { 
[CmdletBinding()]

param ( 
[Parameter (Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
[Alias("I")]
$Image

)

cls
       
foreach ($row in $Image)
{
  foreach ($position in $row) {
    Write-Host "  " -NoNewline -BackgroundColor $Colors[$position]; Start-Sleep -m 10
  }
  Write-Host ""
}
}

PS-Draw -Image $omg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast your `Image` parameter to `[array]` or `[object[]]` and remove `ValueFromPipeline = $True`:

```
function PS-Draw { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( 
        [Parameter (Mandatory = $True)]
        [Alias("I")]
        [array]$Image
    )

    cls
   
    foreach ($row in $Image) {
      foreach ($position in $row) {
        Write-Host "  " -NoNewline -BackgroundColor $Colors[$position]
        Start-Sleep -m 10
      }
      Write-Host ""
    }
}
```

Since the function no longer takes input via the pipeline, you need to call it using

```
PS-Draw -Image $omg
```

OR, if you do want to be able to send the array by piping it to the function, do:

```
function PS-Draw { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( 
        [Parameter (Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        [Alias("I")]
        [object[]]$Image
    )

    # if the data is sent through the pipeline, use $input to collect is as array
    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { $Image = @($input) }

    cls
   
    foreach ($row in $Image) {
      foreach ($position in $row) {
        Write-Host "  " -NoNewline -BackgroundColor $Colors[$position]
        Start-Sleep -m 10
      }
      Write-Host ""
    }
}
```

Now you can also call the function using

```
$omg | PS-Draw
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: ive tried that 

this is the error I get 

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:14 char:5
+     Write-Host "  " -NoNewline -BackgroundColor $Colors[$position]; S ...
+     
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: @JakobyScream I'm using your example and both methods work just fine..

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/YwRuj7V)

im really confused then, I copy and pasted your code and still get the same error. 
You've actually answered other questions I've had before though, you are appreciated

Comment: I stand corrected, I had a minor error, your method works just fine. You are wonderful and again appreciated

Comment: Nice! Though I find `$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` somewhat obscure (at least it is hard to remember). Is there a way using regular `begin`, `process`, `end` blocks (i. e. without special-casing pipeline input)?

Comment: @zett42 AFAIK, you could leave out the line `if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { $Image = @($input) }`, but then you need to prefix the array you're sending with a unary array operator (aka the comma) and call the function with `,$omg | PS-Draw`. In fact, what you are sending is a single-item array, which gets unravelled by PowerShell leaving the function with the original array.